# JBOSS EAP 7.0.6 Domain Deployment not working with CLI file Deployment

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly-10

I have created a cli file to run a deployment for me which is called on by Jenkins and Linux Command line and seems to be failing at startup.  Not sure if I'm missing something.

This is how I call it.
    `sudo /opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=$SERVER --user=$USER --password=$PASS --file=/opt/file/JBOSS/appname/cli/deploy.cli`

It will stop the server, undeploy, and replace the war file in the Content Repository. Problem happens when I go to start it back up, script is not working to start it and I found I have to go into the console and start/restart Server Group from Runtime and then restart the servers. On the slave/host the server is not running. No errors in the logs that I have seen.  Just not sure if I'm taking correct route at this point.  Thanks in Advance.

```
`batch
 /server-group=GroupName:stop-servers(blocking=true)
 undeploy Web.war --server-groups=GroupName
 deploy /tmp/deploys/working/appname/Web.war --server-groups=GroupName
 deployment-info --server-group=GroupName
 /server-group=GroupName:start-servers(blocking=true)
 run-batch`
```

Comment: Is there a reason you stop the servers first? That shouldn't be required.

Comment: You may encounter issue if server is not stopped completely. in batch script user command: "/host=master/server-config=server-one:read-attribute(name=status)" to check server status.  Try to start it once server is in "STOPPED" status.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I ended up having to do it that way due to getting OutOfMemory errors and locking everything up.

Comment: @Abhijit Humbe - That showed the status of "running" so I changed it up to /server-group=GroupName:reload-servers and that seem to do the trick. - Thanks All that got me going in the right direction and it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a follow-up.  I ended up breaking it up into two separate chunks of code and running it via shell script. Not sure what the difference is but it works 100% of the time this way for me.

Call from Shell Script

```
/opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --
controller=$SERVER --user=$USER --password=$PASS --
file=/opt/cli/deploy.cli
```

Batch (deploy.cli)

```
batch
/server-group=GroupName:stop-servers(blocking=true)
undeploy Web.war --server-groups=GroupName
deploy /tmp/deploys/working/appname/Web.war --server-groups=GroupName
run-batch
```

Other Call later in the Shell Script

```
/opt/rh/eap7/root/usr/share/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --
controller=$SERVER --user=$USER --password=$PASS --
file=/opt/cli/start.cli
```

Batch (start.cli)

```
batch 
/server-group=GroupName:start-servers
deployment-info --server-group=GroupName
run-batch
```